# Android: Disable/Enable ImageButton and show different colors

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I would like to achieve following functionalities but confused about how to do it:

1. Initially, the image button is DISABLED and the color(tint) is gray.
2. When click on the image button, meaning ENABLE the button and the color (tint) of the button turns to orange (or other colors) and NOT return to gray.
3. When click on the image button again, meaning DISABLE the button and the color turns gray again.

The code I tried is shown below:

**clickbutton_mic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/big_mic_icon"
            android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"
            />
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" >
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/big_mic_icon"
            android:tint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            />
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/big_mic_icon"/>

</selector>
```

Part of **main_page.xml**

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/clickbutton_mic" />
```

Part of **MainPage.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        btn.setEnabled(false);
    }

public void onClick(ImageButton btn)
    {
        if(!btn.isEnabled()){
            btn.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else{
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

The result of this code is showing the black icon (the original icon color, neither gray or orange) all the time. 
I have found some questions about disable/enable image button on stackoverflow but the answers are not clear to me. So can anyone help me deal with this situation? Thank you!

Comment: You need to post the relevant code of what you've attempted. You've got multiple questions here and it's hard to tell *exactly what you're stuck on*

Comment: @codeMagic Code posted. Thanks for reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself. I misunderstood the meaning of "setEnabled". My following code achieved what I want.

```
private int MIC_STATUS = 0; // MIC OFF
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(MIC_STATUS == 0){ // mic is off, turn on the mic
                    imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(255,42,72));
                    MIC_STATUS = 1;
                }

                else if(MIC_STATUS == 1){ // mic is on, turn off the mic
                    imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
                    MIC_STATUS = 0;
                }

            }
        });
}
```